# WCF REST list HTTP headers on incoming request

Tags: wcf, rest

I've fired up the WCF REST starter kit and am trying to access the HTTP headers on the incoming request. I've looked at OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders but either it doesn't hold them or I'm accessing it wrong.

How do I list the HTTP headers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eventually found the answer.

```
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

protected override IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SampleItem>> OnGetItems() {
    WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
    foreach (string key in headers.Keys) {
        logger.Debug("header " + key + "=" + headers[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you implement this in the .svc file or in the method ?